# Compiling error with gfortran

Tags: compiler-construction, gfortran

I am trying to learn fortran90/95 for a class on vector and parallel scientific computation.  I'm working on Windows Vista 32 bit and I downloaded (what I believe to be, anyway) the version of the gfortran compiler for my operating system from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries).

To test if it was working, I wrote a hello world program as follows:

```
program testfortran
    write(*,*) 'Hello world!"
end program testfortran
```

pretty much verbatim from a fortran tutorial.  When I try to compile it:

```
gfortran testfortran.f90
```

it gives me the following response:

```
C:\Program files\gfortran\bin/1d.exe: cannot open output file a.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: 1d returned 1 exit status
```

As an engineer, pretty much all of my programming experience has been with interpreted languages like Matlab and I'm not very familiar with compiled languages.  I don't know if I'm just making a really dumb error or what.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Yes, thankyou I've moved past these issues.  I apologize for the late response.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, you can accept it; if you thought it was a good answer, you can also upvote it. See the faq link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a.exe: Permission denied` message implies that you don't have permission to write to the current directory. What directory is `testfortran.f90` in? Can you create a file in the same directory (say, `echo hello > hello.txt`)? Can you try it in a different directory? (It does seem odd, though; if you can create `testfortran.f90` in that directory, you should be able to create `a.exe` in the same directory.)

Or perhaps, there's already an `a.exe` file in that directory, and you don't have permission to overwrite it.  Try

```
gfortran testfortran.f90 -o testfortran.exe
```

Also, your error message refers to `1d.exe`. I would expect it to be `ld.exe`, the linker. And your sample program has mismatched quotation marks: `'Hello world!"`. It's best to copy-and-paste your source code and any error messages rather than re-typing them.

Comment: Sorry about the typos, I'll try to just copy code instead of retyping it from now on.  In answer to your question, gfortran is currently in the directory 

    C:\Program Files\gfortran\bin\

and I was under the impression that a file had to be in this directory for gfortran to operate on it.  But I apparently don't have direct write permission to that directory, so I just saved the .f90 file somewhere else and moved it manually to the directory.

Comment: @clioi: That `bin` directory is *only* for binary files (executables) that are part of gfortran itself. Your own working files should be somewhere under your own home directory.